# Increment number per button click C# Desktop

Tags: c#, windows

I'm trying to create a mathematical game with a timer that calculates the number of correct questions within a specific time. Now I'm trying to increment an `int` value per button click if the answer is correct.

But it only increment once and sometimes does not increment:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int x = Randomnumber.Next(12);
    int z = Randomnumber.Next(12);
    int s = x * z;
    int correct = 0;
    //int cv = +correct;
    textBox2.Text = x.ToString();
    textBox3.Text = z.ToString();
    if (s == Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text))
    {
        correct += 1;
        numbercorrect.Text = correct.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

your main form(i'm assuming you're using forms)  is a class.

What I'd suggest is declaring a variable as a member of your forms class, and using that to hold the number of correct responses.

I'd imagine something like the following;

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int correct;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //insert logic here
            correct++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to move `int correct` declaration to **[class scope](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpVariableScopes.aspx)**. Otherwise with every click, you start with new variable.

Answer (score 2):

`int correct = 0;` is scoped within the function. Move it outside the function as a class field. That way it will preserve its value instead of being reset to `0` during each click.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private int correct = 0;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int x = Randomnumber.Next(12);
    int z = Randomnumber.Next(12);
    int s = x * z;
    //int cv = +correct;
    textBox2.Text = x.ToString();
    textBox3.Text = z.ToString();
    if (s == Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text))
    {
        correct ++;
        numbercorrect.Text = correct.ToString();
    }
```

You always start your count with 0, and never get the original value.
Now the variable holding the data is outside the function and initialized when the form loads.

Answer (score 0):

Every time the button is clicked, `correct` is beging reset to zero. 
Try declaring `correct` outside of the method.

Answer (score 0):

Try look at code bellow:

```
int correct = 0;
tryParse(numbercorrect.Text, out correct);
```

So your code must be like:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int x = Randomnumber.Next(12);
    int z = Randomnumber.Next(12);
    int s = x * z;
    int correct = 0;
    int.tryParse(numbercorrect.Text, out correct);
    //int cv = +correct;
    textBox2.Text = x.ToString();
    textBox3.Text = z.ToString();
    if (s == Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text))
    {
        correct += 1;
        numbercorrect.Text = correct.ToString();

    }
```